# Solid of revolution volume.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have the following problem.

A quadratic curve have the following description:

$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    f(2) = 0 & \\
    f'(2) = 0 & \\
    f'(1) = -2
  \end{array} \right.
$$

From this constraints I found: $$f(x) = X^2-4x+4$$

Now I should take the curve from 0 to 1 and use it as a lathe model. Now if the material I want to cut have a diameter of:

$$\frac{8}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

And lenght of:

$$2$$

What is the volume of the conical object that is obtained.

Any help would be appreciated.

*Edit:*

I'm not realy sure about the lathe part, but my guess is I have to find the volume of evolution of the gray area.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is that you're saying, but if you're saying that you want a cone with diameter $8/\sqrt{\pi}$ and length $2$ then the answer is $2\pi r^2$ where $r=4/\sqrt{\pi}$ is the radius and hence 32.

Comment: added a little update. maybe now the question is a little more clear

Comment: First, the value of $x$ at which the red line intersects with the curve is $z=2-\sqrt{r}$ (set $(x-2)^2$ equal to $r$).  That gives you a rectangle of size $zr$ plus the area under the curve from $z$ to $2$, i.e. $\int_z^2 (2-x)^2 dx =(2-z)^3/3$.